# multi format string conversions

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below 2 cases of XML.

```
<pg>1/2/1, 1/4/2, 1/4/7, 1/4/8, 1/9/1, 1A/0/11, 3/0/2, 10/1/6, 12/0/2, 12/3/1, 15/2/1, 17/5/2, 19/0/2A, 25/1/1, 28/0/2, 41/1/5, 55/0/2, 55/1/1, 62/3/3, 65/0/2, 65/2/1, 65/4/1, 65/5/4, 69/4/1, 70/0/3, 72/2/11, 72/2/19, 72/6/5, 75/0/2, 75/1/18, 76/0/2, 77/0/3, 78/0/2, 81/1/12, 92/0/2, 100/3/1, 103/0/52, 103/0/53, 121/0/2A, PD1.1/1, PD5.1/2, PD5.4/1, PD18.1/49, B/74, B/75, B/76, P1/1, P1/2, P3/0/2, P3/0/3, P–FM–D4, D4/65, E1/28/1, F1/30/5, F1/35/2, F1/35/5, H1/3, H9/2, J1/60, M2/18, Q1/25/2, R1/10/1, U1/0/4, U1/0/22, U1/112/2, V1/0/2, V2/0/1, V2/1/0 </pg>
```

and

```
<pg>4/9/2, 5/4, 6/2/9, 6/L/27, 13/9/3, 13/9/14, 14/0/2, 14/0/4, 14/1/1—14/1/5, 14/1/7—14/1/10, 14/2/1—14/2/3, 14/2/5, 14/2/7, 14/4/1, 14/4/3, 14/4/4, 14/4/8—14/4/10, 14/4/12, 14/4/14, 14/4/18, 14/4/19, 14/4/21, 14/4/22, 14/4/25, 14/4/26, 14/4/29, 14/4/30, 14/4/33, 14/4/34, 14/4/36, 14/4/37, 14/4/41, 14/4/42, 14/5/1, 14/6/1, 14/7/1—14/7/6, 14/7/8, 14/7/9, 14/7/15, 14/7/18, 14/8/1, 14/8/2, 14/9/1, 14/10/1, 14/11/1, 14A/0/2, 14A/0/3, 14A/2/7, 15/2/3, 15/3/6, 15/4/11, 16/4/9, 16/7/3, 16/8/8, 16/8/10, 16/11/1, 18/1/3, 18/2/5, 19/2/2, 19/2/9, 20/0/2, 20/4/3, 20/8/23, 22/8, 23/3/3, 24/7/1, 25/1, 27/3/6, 28/4/1, 29/10, 29/10/3, 29/11/1, 29/12/4, 32/6/4, 32/6/14, 32/13/8, 33/0/3, 33/4/1, 42/1/4, 42/2/4, 43/1/5, 45/4/2, 47/1/1, 47/1/2, 58/1/4, 59/0/9, 59/0/47, 59/0/55, 59/4, 59/10/35, 62/4/2, 62/App/21, 62/App/27, 71/2/1, 76/6/1, 81/4/2, 81/5/7, 86/0/2, 86/0/3, 86/1/1, 86/1/2, 86/1/3, 86/2/2, 86/4/1, 88/0/2, 88/1/2, 100/3/13, 103/0/26, 103/0/28, 113/0/2, PD8.2/1, PD8.2/2, PD14.1/1, PD16.2/5, E3/0/4</pg>
```

Below is the XSLT(REGEX).

```
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)|
            ([0-9]+)([A-Z])/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)|
            ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)([A-Z])/([0-9]+)|
            ([A-Z])([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)|
            ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)([A-Z])">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <a href="{concat('er:#HKWBV1_ORD_',format-number(number(regex-group(1)),'00'),'/P',format-number(number(regex-group(1)),'0'),'/',regex-group(2),'/',regex-group(3))}">

                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </a>

                </xsl:matching-substring>


            <xsl:non-matching-substring>

                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <a href="{concat('er:#HKWBV1_ORD_',format-number(number(regex-group(1)),'00'),'/P',format-number(number(regex-group(1)),'0'),'/',regex-group(2))}">

                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </a>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>

                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
              </xsl:analyze-string>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

I am trying to convert into the below part

```
er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/2/1
```

here

```
er:#HKWBV1_ORD_(content before first slash)/P1(even here number before first slash)/2(content before second slash)/1(content after 2nd slash).
```

But i/m getting the below result.

```
<td class="pgs"><a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/0/2">1/0/2</a>,<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/2/1">1/2/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/4/2">1/4/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/4/7">1/4/7</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/4/8">1/4/8</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/9/1">1/9/1</a>, 1A/<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_00/P0/11">0/11</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_03/P3/0/2">3/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_10/P10/1/6">10/1/6</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_12/P12/0/2">12/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_12/P12/3/1">12/3/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_15/P15/2/1">15/2/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_17/P17/5/2">17/5/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_19/P19/0/2">19/0/2</a>A, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_25/P25/1/1">25/1/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_28/P28/0/2">28/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_41/P41/1/5">41/1/5</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_55/P55/0/2">55/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_55/P55/1/1">55/1/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_62/P62/3/3">62/3/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_65/P65/0/2">65/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_65/P65/2/1">65/2/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_65/P65/4/1">65/4/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_65/P65/5/4">65/5/4</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_69/P69/4/1">69/4/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_70/P70/0/3">70/0/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_72/P72/2/11">72/2/11</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_72/P72/2/19">72/2/19</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_72/P72/6/5">72/6/5</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_75/P75/0/2">75/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_75/P75/1/18">75/1/18</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_76/P76/0/2">76/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_77/P77/0/3">77/0/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_78/P78/0/2">78/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_81/P81/1/12">81/1/12</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_92/P92/0/2">92/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_100/P100/3/1">100/3/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_103/P103/0/52">103/0/52</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_103/P103/0/53">103/0/53</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_121/P121/0/2">121/0/2</a>A, PD1.<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/1">1/1</a>, PD5.<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/2">1/2</a>, PD5.<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_04/P4/1">4/1</a>, PD18.<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/49">1/49</a>, B/74, B/75, B/76, P<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/1">1/1</a>, P<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/2">1/2</a>, P<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_03/P3/0/2">3/0/2</a>, P<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_03/P3/0/3">3/0/3</a>, P–FM–D4, D<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_04/P4/65">4/65</a>, E<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/28/1">1/28/1</a>, F<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/30/5">1/30/5</a>, F<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/35/2">1/35/2</a>, F<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/35/5">1/35/5</a>, H<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/3">1/3</a>, H<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_09/P9/2">9/2</a>, J<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/60">1/60</a>, M<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_02/P2/18">2/18</a>, Q<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/25/2">1/25/2</a>, R<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/10/1">1/10/1</a>, U<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/0/4">1/0/4</a>, U<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/0/22">1/0/22</a>, U<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/112/2">1/112/2</a>, V<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/0/2">1/0/2</a>, V<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_02/P2/0/1">2/0/1</a>, V<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_02/P2/1/0">2/1/0</a> </td>
```

please let me know how i can get my output in above mentioned format. I already got a reply that was working fine but, when i encounter a M-Dash(Long hyphen), string before and after hyphen are getting joined as a single link.

If there is any number like

```
 D4/65, E1/28/1, F1/30/5, F1/35/2, F1/35/5, H1/3, H9/2, J1/60, M2/18, Q1/25/2, R1/10/1, U1/0/4, U1/0/22, U1/112/2, V1/0/2, V2/0/1, V2/1/0
```

should be converted as

```
<span class="invalid">D4/65</span>, <span class="invalid">E1/28/1</span>
```

here the trick is if the number is followeb by character, it should give the above output and

if the input has the following

```
PD2.2/4, PD5.6/8/9
```

it should convert it as

```
er:#HKWBV1_SEC_2.2/P2.2/4 and er:#HKWBV1_SEC_5.6/P5.6/8/9
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that it would be easier to match anything that wasn't a space or comma in your regex. Then instead of an additional `xsl:analyze-string`, use `tokenize`.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<test>
    <pg>1/2/1, 1/4/2, 1/4/7, 1/4/8, 1/9/1, 1A/0/11, 3/0/2, 10/1/6, 12/0/2, 12/3/1, 15/2/1, 17/5/2, 19/0/2A, 25/1/1, 28/0/2, 41/1/5, 55/0/2, 55/1/1, 62/3/3, 65/0/2, 65/2/1, 65/4/1, 65/5/4, 69/4/1, 70/0/3, 72/2/11, 72/2/19, 72/6/5, 75/0/2, 75/1/18, 76/0/2, 77/0/3, 78/0/2, 81/1/12, 92/0/2, 100/3/1, 103/0/52, 103/0/53, 121/0/2A, PD1.1/1, PD5.1/2, PD5.4/1, PD18.1/49, B/74, B/75, B/76, P1/1, P1/2, P3/0/2, P3/0/3, P–FM–D4, D4/65, E1/28/1, F1/30/5, F1/35/2, F1/35/5, H1/3, H9/2, J1/60, M2/18, Q1/25/2, R1/10/1, U1/0/4, U1/0/22, U1/112/2, V1/0/2, V2/0/1, V2/1/0 </pg>
    <pg>4/9/2, 5/4, 6/2/9, 6/L/27, 13/9/3, 13/9/14, 14/0/2, 14/0/4, 14/1/1—14/1/5, 14/1/7—14/1/10, 14/2/1—14/2/3, 14/2/5, 14/2/7, 14/4/1, 14/4/3, 14/4/4, 14/4/8—14/4/10, 14/4/12, 14/4/14, 14/4/18, 14/4/19, 14/4/21, 14/4/22, 14/4/25, 14/4/26, 14/4/29, 14/4/30, 14/4/33, 14/4/34, 14/4/36, 14/4/37, 14/4/41, 14/4/42, 14/5/1, 14/6/1, 14/7/1—14/7/6, 14/7/8, 14/7/9, 14/7/15, 14/7/18, 14/8/1, 14/8/2, 14/9/1, 14/10/1, 14/11/1, 14A/0/2, 14A/0/3, 14A/2/7, 15/2/3, 15/3/6, 15/4/11, 16/4/9, 16/7/3, 16/8/8, 16/8/10, 16/11/1, 18/1/3, 18/2/5, 19/2/2, 19/2/9, 20/0/2, 20/4/3, 20/8/23, 22/8, 23/3/3, 24/7/1, 25/1, 27/3/6, 28/4/1, 29/10, 29/10/3, 29/11/1, 29/12/4, 32/6/4, 32/6/14, 32/13/8, 33/0/3, 33/4/1, 42/1/4, 42/2/4, 43/1/5, 45/4/2, 47/1/1, 47/1/2, 58/1/4, 59/0/9, 59/0/47, 59/0/55, 59/4, 59/10/35, 62/4/2, 62/App/21, 62/App/27, 71/2/1, 76/6/1, 81/4/2, 81/5/7, 86/0/2, 86/0/3, 86/1/1, 86/1/2, 86/1/3, 86/2/2, 86/4/1, 88/0/2, 88/1/2, 100/3/13, 103/0/26, 103/0/28, 113/0/2, PD8.2/1, PD8.2/2, PD14.1/1, PD16.2/5, E3/0/4</pg>
</test>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pg">
        <td class="pgs">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[^,\s—]+">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:variable name="pg" select="tokenize(.,'/')"/>
                    <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_{
                        if (string(number($pg[1]))!='NaN') then 
                            format-number(number($pg[1]),'00') 
                        else 
                            $pg[1]}/P{$pg[1]
                        }/{string-join($pg[position()>1],'/')}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </a>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>           
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<test>
   <td class="pgs">
      <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/2/1">1/2/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/4/2">1/4/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/4/7">1/4/7</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/4/8">1/4/8</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_01/P1/9/1">1/9/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_1A/P1A/0/11">1A/0/11</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_03/P3/0/2">3/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_10/P10/1/6">10/1/6</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_12/P12/0/2">12/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_12/P12/3/1">12/3/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_15/P15/2/1">15/2/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_17/P17/5/2">17/5/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_19/P19/0/2A">19/0/2A</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_25/P25/1/1">25/1/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_28/P28/0/2">28/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_41/P41/1/5">41/1/5</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_55/P55/0/2">55/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_55/P55/1/1">55/1/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_62/P62/3/3">62/3/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_65/P65/0/2">65/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_65/P65/2/1">65/2/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_65/P65/4/1">65/4/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_65/P65/5/4">65/5/4</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_69/P69/4/1">69/4/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_70/P70/0/3">70/0/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_72/P72/2/11">72/2/11</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_72/P72/2/19">72/2/19</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_72/P72/6/5">72/6/5</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_75/P75/0/2">75/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_75/P75/1/18">75/1/18</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_76/P76/0/2">76/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_77/P77/0/3">77/0/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_78/P78/0/2">78/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_81/P81/1/12">81/1/12</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_92/P92/0/2">92/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_100/P100/3/1">100/3/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_103/P103/0/52">103/0/52</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_103/P103/0/53">103/0/53</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_121/P121/0/2A">121/0/2A</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_PD1.1/PPD1.1/1">PD1.1/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_PD5.1/PPD5.1/2">PD5.1/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_PD5.4/PPD5.4/1">PD5.4/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_PD18.1/PPD18.1/49">PD18.1/49</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_B/PB/74">B/74</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_B/PB/75">B/75</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_B/PB/76">B/76</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_P1/PP1/1">P1/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_P1/PP1/2">P1/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_P3/PP3/0/2">P3/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_P3/PP3/0/3">P3/0/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_P–FM–D4/PP–FM–D4/">P–FM–D4</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_D4/PD4/65">D4/65</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_E1/PE1/28/1">E1/28/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_F1/PF1/30/5">F1/30/5</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_F1/PF1/35/2">F1/35/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_F1/PF1/35/5">F1/35/5</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_H1/PH1/3">H1/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_H9/PH9/2">H9/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_J1/PJ1/60">J1/60</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_M2/PM2/18">M2/18</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_Q1/PQ1/25/2">Q1/25/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_R1/PR1/10/1">R1/10/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_U1/PU1/0/4">U1/0/4</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_U1/PU1/0/22">U1/0/22</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_U1/PU1/112/2">U1/112/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_V1/PV1/0/2">V1/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_V2/PV2/0/1">V2/0/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_V2/PV2/1/0">V2/1/0</a> 
   </td>
   <td class="pgs">
      <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_04/P4/9/2">4/9/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_05/P5/4">5/4</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_06/P6/2/9">6/2/9</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_06/P6/L/27">6/L/27</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_13/P13/9/3">13/9/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_13/P13/9/14">13/9/14</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/0/2">14/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/0/4">14/0/4</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/1/1">14/1/1</a>—<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/1/5">14/1/5</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/1/7">14/1/7</a>—<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/1/10">14/1/10</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/2/1">14/2/1</a>—<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/2/3">14/2/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/2/5">14/2/5</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/2/7">14/2/7</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/1">14/4/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/3">14/4/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/4">14/4/4</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/8">14/4/8</a>—<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/10">14/4/10</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/12">14/4/12</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/14">14/4/14</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/18">14/4/18</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/19">14/4/19</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/21">14/4/21</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/22">14/4/22</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/25">14/4/25</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/26">14/4/26</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/29">14/4/29</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/30">14/4/30</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/33">14/4/33</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/34">14/4/34</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/36">14/4/36</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/37">14/4/37</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/41">14/4/41</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/4/42">14/4/42</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/5/1">14/5/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/6/1">14/6/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/7/1">14/7/1</a>—<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/7/6">14/7/6</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/7/8">14/7/8</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/7/9">14/7/9</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/7/15">14/7/15</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/7/18">14/7/18</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/8/1">14/8/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/8/2">14/8/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/9/1">14/9/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/10/1">14/10/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14/P14/11/1">14/11/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14A/P14A/0/2">14A/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14A/P14A/0/3">14A/0/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_14A/P14A/2/7">14A/2/7</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_15/P15/2/3">15/2/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_15/P15/3/6">15/3/6</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_15/P15/4/11">15/4/11</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_16/P16/4/9">16/4/9</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_16/P16/7/3">16/7/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_16/P16/8/8">16/8/8</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_16/P16/8/10">16/8/10</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_16/P16/11/1">16/11/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_18/P18/1/3">18/1/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_18/P18/2/5">18/2/5</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_19/P19/2/2">19/2/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_19/P19/2/9">19/2/9</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_20/P20/0/2">20/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_20/P20/4/3">20/4/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_20/P20/8/23">20/8/23</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_22/P22/8">22/8</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_23/P23/3/3">23/3/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_24/P24/7/1">24/7/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_25/P25/1">25/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_27/P27/3/6">27/3/6</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_28/P28/4/1">28/4/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_29/P29/10">29/10</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_29/P29/10/3">29/10/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_29/P29/11/1">29/11/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_29/P29/12/4">29/12/4</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_32/P32/6/4">32/6/4</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_32/P32/6/14">32/6/14</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_32/P32/13/8">32/13/8</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_33/P33/0/3">33/0/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_33/P33/4/1">33/4/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_42/P42/1/4">42/1/4</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_42/P42/2/4">42/2/4</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_43/P43/1/5">43/1/5</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_45/P45/4/2">45/4/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_47/P47/1/1">47/1/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_47/P47/1/2">47/1/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_58/P58/1/4">58/1/4</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_59/P59/0/9">59/0/9</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_59/P59/0/47">59/0/47</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_59/P59/0/55">59/0/55</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_59/P59/4">59/4</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_59/P59/10/35">59/10/35</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_62/P62/4/2">62/4/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_62/P62/App/21">62/App/21</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_62/P62/App/27">62/App/27</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_71/P71/2/1">71/2/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_76/P76/6/1">76/6/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_81/P81/4/2">81/4/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_81/P81/5/7">81/5/7</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_86/P86/0/2">86/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_86/P86/0/3">86/0/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_86/P86/1/1">86/1/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_86/P86/1/2">86/1/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_86/P86/1/3">86/1/3</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_86/P86/2/2">86/2/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_86/P86/4/1">86/4/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_88/P88/0/2">88/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_88/P88/1/2">88/1/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_100/P100/3/13">100/3/13</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_103/P103/0/26">103/0/26</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_103/P103/0/28">103/0/28</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_113/P113/0/2">113/0/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_PD8.2/PPD8.2/1">PD8.2/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_PD8.2/PPD8.2/2">PD8.2/2</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_PD14.1/PPD14.1/1">PD14.1/1</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_PD16.2/PPD16.2/5">PD16.2/5</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_E3/PE3/0/4">E3/0/4</a>
   </td>
</test>
```

---

**Explanation**

To explain the regex and tokenization, lets use a smaller example:

```
<pg>1/2/1, 1/4/2</pg>
```

The regex `regex="[^,\s—]+"` in the `xsl:analyze-string` is matching one or more characters that aren't a `,`, `\s` (white space), or `—`. The `^` at the beginning of the character class means "not".

Using the shortened example, we would have these 2 matches (`xsl:matching-substring`):

`1/2/1` and `1/4/2`

The `,` would be output by `xsl:non-matching-substring`.

Since the matching-substrings are delimited by `/`, we can use `tokenize()` to get a sequence of values we can use. The values can be easily accessed by their position.

For example, `1/4/2` ends up being 3 items in a sequence:

`1` = first item
`4` = second item
`2` = third item

An example of this in my answer above is my use of `$pg[1]`. This is the first item in the sequence of the variable `pg`.

Another example is `string-join($pg[position()>1],'/')`. This joins all of the items whos position is greater than one. Using our `1/4/2` example, we would get `4/2` because `4` is the second item and `2` is the third item. The `/` comes from the second argument in `string-join()`.

Using regex and tokenize make it fairly easy to do complex string manipulation. For example, it would be possible to output an individual entry for each value in the the "mdash" ranges. An example would be:

`102/9—102/12` (102/9 through 102/12)

becomes:

```
<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_102/P102/9">102/9</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_102/P102/10">102/10</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_102/P102/11">102/11</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_102/P102/12">102/12</a>
```

The code wouldn't really be that much more complex:

```
<xsl:template match="pg">
    <td class="pgs">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[^,\s]+">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:variable name="range" select="tokenize(.,'—')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="pg" select="tokenize(.,'/')"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($pg[3],'—')">
                        <xsl:variable name="range-pg" as="item()*">
                            <xsl:for-each select="$range">
                                <xsl:sequence select="tokenize(.,'/')"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:for-each select="xs:integer($range-pg[3]) to xs:integer($range-pg[6])">
                            <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_{
                                if (string(number($range-pg[1]))!='NaN') then 
                                format-number(number($range-pg[1]),'00') 
                                else 
                                $range-pg[1]}/P{string-join($range-pg[position()=(1,2)],'/')}/{.}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat(string-join($range-pg[position()=(1,2)],'/'),'/',.)"/>
                            </a>
                            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_{
                            if (string(number($pg[1]))!='NaN') then 
                            format-number(number($pg[1]),'00') 
                            else 
                            $pg[1]}/P{$pg[1]
                            }/{string-join($pg[position()>1],'/')}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </a>                            
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>           
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel Haley, Thanks for making my burden ease. This is working, but if you see the last one, it is giving as `<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_NaN/PV2/1/0">V2/1/0</a>` where as i want it to be like `<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_V2/PV2/1/0">V2/1/0</a>`

Comment: I also updated my question, can you please look into it, as the code you gave is not working for Hyphens :-(

Comment: @user2423959 - what should the output of the hyphens/mdashes look like?

Comment: Same as given above but there should be a M-Dash in between like, Eg:  `102/9—102/12` should be converted as `<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_102/P102/9">102/9</a>—<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_102/P102/12">102/12</a>`. Also, can please look into my previous comment. Thanks

Comment: @user2423959 - You need to add the mdash to the regex and then add a check to see if the content before the first slash is a number. Please see my edit for a complete example.

Comment: Thank you verymuch, you are rally awesome, This is what i want, but a last question, can you please explain me what is going on in those regex and string tokenizing. I'm just curious to know. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2423959 - You're very welcome. I added an explanation. Hopefully it makes sense. If not, let me know and I'll try to explain further.

Comment: Hi Daniel i came across another situation :-(. please look the question updated one. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Daniel, i'm stuck again in my regex can you please have a look into my code?

Comment: @user2423959 - I will try to look at it tonight (about 8 hrs from now).